# How to make minting function that takes 0.1 ethereum in Solidity?

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, nft, hardhat

Can someone please explain how can I make a function that mints a token for 0.1 eth in Solidity and verify it in HardHat? I have done this so far:

HardHat:

```js
[owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
const Nft = await ethers.getContractFactory("contract");
const nft = await Nft.deploy(owner.address);

prov = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
let balance = await prov.getBalance(owner.address);
console.log(balance); <-- evaluates to 10000000000000

await hoodie.mint({ value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1") });

console.log(balance); <-- still evaluates to 10000000000000
```

Solidity:

```
function mint() payable public returns (uint256) {;
        require(msg.value == 0.1 ether || msg.value == 100000000000000000 wei, "Transaction amount has to be 0.1 eth");

        _safeMint(msg.sender, token_id);

        return token_id;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to mint an NFT and transfer 0.1 ether to the contract, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that case,

you may try adding approve and transferFrom methods.

**approve** is needed to make you approve the fund transfer

**transferFrom** is needed to make the fund transfer happen

the contract:

```
function mint() payable public returns (uint256) {
     require(msg.value == 0.1 ether || msg.value == 100000000000000000 
         wei, "Transaction amount has to be 0.1 eth");

     IERC20(*the ETH address here*).approve(msg.sender, msg.value);
     IERC20(*the ETH address here*).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), msg.value);

      _safeMint(msg.sender, token_id);

     return token_id;
    }
```

Comment: Is this implementation also true for ERC721, forgot to mention that I was using that standard?

Comment: yes, it's all about transfering funds from an address to another

Answer (score 0):

You need to use payable to transfer native token such as ETH or BNB in smart contract.

And then you can call `_safeMint()` private function with token ID.
You also need to increase token ID after mint.

```
function mint() payable public returns (uint256) {
  require(msg.value == 0.1 ether || msg.value == 100000000000000000 
    wei, "Transaction amount has to be 0.1 eth");

  payable(this).transfer(msg.value);

  _safeMint(msg.sender, token_id);

  token_id.increament();

  return token_id;
}
```